# View dataframes by pasting its name in r

Tags: r, view, paste

Is there any way to View dataframes in r, while refering to them with another variable? Say I have 10 data frames named df1 to df10, is there a way I can View them while using i instead of 1:10?
Example:

```
df1 = as.data.frame(c(1:20))
i = 1

View(paste("df", i, sep =""))
```

I would like this last piece of code to do the same as View(df1). Is there any command or similar in R that allows you to do that?

Comment: Try `View(eval(parse(text=paste("df", i, sep =""))))`.

Comment: I feel compelled to say please do _not_ try anything involving `eval(parse(text = ...))`, and I feel a little bad for even letting you know about `get`, to be perfectly honest.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your immediate question is `get`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 6:10)
> get(paste0("df",1))
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
```

But having multiple similar objects with names like `df1`, `df2`, etc in your workspace is considered fairly bad practice in R, and instead experienced R folks will prefer to put related objects in a named list:

```
df_list <- setNames(list(df1,df2),paste0("df",1:2))
> df_list[[paste0("df",1)]]
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
```

Comment: Thank you. get worked fine! However, are there any way to save things to this dataframes using the same way? If i write get(paste0("df",1))$a = 3, I get the error that "target of assignment expands to non-language object".

Comment: @Alfemann Remember, I _told_ you that `get` was a bad idea, but somehow no one ever listens. Try the other option and do `df_list[[paste0("df",1)]]$y <- letters[1:5]`.