# Function in R to rename variables and compute R code

Tags: r, function

I would like to write a function which takes a list of variables out of a dataframe, say:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5), b = c(6,7,8,9,10))
```

And to compute always the same calculation, say calculate the standard deviation like:

```
test.function <- function(var){ 
  for (i in var) {
  paste0(i, "_per_sd") <-  i / sd(i)
  }
  }
```

In order to create a new variable a_per_sd which is divided by it's standard deviation. Unfortunately, I am stuck and get a `Error in paste0(i, "_per_sd") <- i/sd(i) :  could not find function "paste0<-"` error.

The expected usage should be:

```
test.function(df$a, df$b)
```

The expected result should be:

```
> df$a_per_sd
[1] 0.6324555 1.2649111 1.8973666 2.5298221 3.1622777
```

And for every other variable which was given.
Somehow I think I should use as.formula and/or eval, but I might be doing a thinking error.
Thank you very much for your attention and help.

Comment: Where do you get the `sd`s? Getting `sd` of the same value doesn't seem intuitive to me.

Comment: The standard deviation should be calculated on the entire column (i in this case in the loop). In this case the sd of the entire df$a is 1.581139, and I would like every single row of the variable to be divided by sd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```r
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5), b = c(6,7,8,9,10))

test.function <- function(...){
    x <- list(...)
    xn <- paste0(unlist(eval(substitute(alist(...)))),
                 "_per_sd")
    setNames(lapply(x, function(y) y/sd(y)), xn)
}

cbind(df, test.function(df$a, df$b))
#>   a  b df$a_per_sd df$b_per_sd
#> 1 1  6   0.6324555    3.794733
#> 2 2  7   1.2649111    4.427189
#> 3 3  8   1.8973666    5.059644
#> 4 4  9   2.5298221    5.692100
#> 5 5 10   3.1622777    6.324555
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick!! Very elegant to use (...) for many parameters in functions... did not know this. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The question is not completely clear to me, but you might get sd of rows/columns or vectors by these approaches:

```
apply(as.matrix(df), MARGIN = 1, FUN = sd) #across rows
#[1] 3.535534 3.535534 3.535534 3.535534 3.535534

apply(as.matrix(df), MARGIN = 2, FUN = sd) #across columns
#       a        b 
#1.581139 1.581139 

lapply(df, sd) #if you provide list of vectors (columns of `df` in this case)
#$a
#[1] 1.581139
#
#$b
#[1] 1.581139
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However, with this approach I cannot pass a specific variable of a dataframe and I would like that specific variable to be renamed and divided by the standard deviation of the entire column.

Answer (score 1):

I got this far. Is this what you are looking for?

```
test.function <- function(var)
  
{
 newvar = paste(var, "_per_sd")
 assign(newvar, var/sd(var))
 get(newvar)
 
 }
```

Input:

```
test.function(df$a)
```

Result:

```
[1] 0.6324555 1.2649111 1.8973666 2.5298221 3.1622777
```

I got the idea from here: [Assignment using get() and paste()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604166/assignment-using-get-and-paste)

Comment: Dear Type Writer, thank you very much. This is very close... I still need two features in it: 1. A loop to enter more than one variables like test.function(df$a, df$b...) and
2. the possibility to include the new variable in the existing dataframe df. 
If we could achive this too, it would be great! Thanks again.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way, but I'm still learning. This is a helpful link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48694626/creating-a-function-in-r-with-variable-number-of-arguments

Answer (score 1):

At the end this is what my code looks like:

```
    test.function <- function(...){
    x <- list(...)
    xn <- paste0(unlist(eval(substitute(alist(...)))),
                 "_per_sd")
    setNames(lapply(x, function(y) y/sd(y, na.rm = TRUE)), xn)
    }
test.function.wrap  <- function(..., dataframe) {
  assign(deparse(substitute(dataframe)),   cbind(dataframe, test.function(...)) , envir=.GlobalEnv) 
}


test.function.wrap(df$a, df$b , dataframe = df)
```

To be able to assign the new variables to the existing dataframe, I put the (absolutely genius) tips together and wrapped the function in another function to do the trick. I am aware it might not be as elegant, but it does the work!